# Utilisation de  « de raisonnable » à la place de « raisonnable »

Tags: expressions, adjectifs, prépositions

Quelle est la fonction  de *de* dans la phrase « quelqu'un d'aussi raisonnable que » ?

« *Mon cher professeur, quelqu'un d'aussi raisonnable que vous ne devrait pas hésiter à prononcer son nom, ne croyez-vous pas?* »

Cette phrase, tiré du livre *Harry Potter à l'école des sorciers* me laisse perplexe : pourquoi ***de** raisonnable* ?

J'ai cherché dans plusieurs œuvres de référence pour trouver les utilisations de *raisonnable* précédé de *de*, e.g. [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/raisonnable)  et je n'ai rien trouvé. Pourquoi ajouter ainsi *de* à un adjectif ?  Est-ce qu'on peut le faire pour tous les adjectifs ?  e.g. « Un livre de rouge » au lieu de « Un livre rouge » ?

Serait-il préférable d'employer « quelqu'un aussi raisonnable que vous » à la place ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Les deux constructions *quelqu'un d'aussi raisonnable que vous* et *quelqu'un aussi raisonnable que vous* sont ici équivalentes et je ne pense pas que l'une soit préférable à l'autre.

La préposition **de**  indique ici le rapport attributif et elle est facultative dans la phrase que tu cites. Par contre si on gardait le verbe **être** pour exprimer le rapport attributif on ne pourrait pas employer *de* et il faudrait dire : *« ... quelqu'un qui est aussi raisonnable que vous ne... »*
(Explication adaptée de *La Grammaire Larousse du français contemporain*.

On ne peut employer cette construction que si l'adjectif est employé comme attribut.  On ne pourrait pas dire *« Un livre de rouge. »* parce que rouge est ici épithète.
 Par contre « *Je vois quelque chose de rouge* » ou « *Il y a un livre de rouge.* » est correct, *rouge* étant attribut dans ces deux phrases.

Answer (score 3):

Le complément de « [quelqu'un](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quelqu%27un) » est introduit par « de » (entrée II a 1 b dans le TLFi).

Comment: Précisons qu'il n'y a pas besoin que ce soit l'adjectif « raisonnable »… On peut tout à fait dire ***« dessinez-moi quelque chose de beau »***, par exemple.